# Webscraping with rvest, error "no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character""

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use rvest package to scrape job titles from webpage, but getting an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_first") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Any advice? Am I missing some part of the code? My code is below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url <- "https://www.cvmarket.lt/darbo-skelbimai"
# save the url
html <- read_html(url) # read the url 

get_links <- function(html) {
  html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "limited-lines", " " ))]') %>%
    html_attr(name = "href")
}
# now we call the function and save it
links <- get_links(html)
links

links <- paste0("https://www.cvmarket.lt", links)

link <- links[1]
html <- read_html(link)


# position title
get_title <- function(html) {
  html %>%
    html_node(xpath = '//*[(@id = "main-job-title")]') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    unlist()
}
#test
get_title(link)
```

Comment: you're calling get_link on the URL string, not the HTML page

Comment: Do some basic debugging for us. Where does this error get thrown? After the call to `get_links()`?

Comment: This error comes after `get_title(link)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico how can I fix that?

Comment: use the output of `read_html` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your functions to accept an uri as input parameter. Use faster css selectors with more specificity so that you get faster matching, in the case of using id, and no duplicates, in the case of the css class combination. You can use url_absolute to complete urls within the get_links function. This also handles the current error where you are passing an url, instead of html, into your get_title function and then calling read_html on it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

get_links <- function(url) {
  read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes('.main-column > .f_job_title') %>%
    html_attr(name = "href") %>% url_absolute(url)
}

# position title
get_title <- function(link) {
  read_html(link) %>%
    html_node('#main-job-title') %>%
    html_text() 
}


url <- "https://www.cvmarket.lt/darbo-skelbimai"
links <- get_links(url)
link <- links[1]

#test
get_title(link)
```